# Why are my instance variables not existing across methods of the same class in ruby?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, class-instance-variables

I am doing the ruby koans and I am on the DiceSet project. I've made the DiceSet class but my instance variables don't seem to persist with the instance like I thought they would. My code is

```
class DiceSet
   attr_reader :values
   @values = []
   puts @values.class
   def roll(number_of_rolls)
     (1..number_of_rolls).each do |roll|
       puts @values.class
       @values << (1..6).to_a.sample
     end
     return @values
   end
end
```

The koan then uses my DiceSet class with

```
dice = DiceSet.new
dice.roll(5)
puts dice.values.class
assert dice.values.is?(Array)
```

I put the puts commands in there to follow whats happening with the @values instance variable and only the first puts @values.class says its an Array class. All the others are returning NilClass. Am I using instance variables incorrectly or is there something else I am missing? Do instance variables get deallocated after a method call?

EDIT: My class works correctly now that I have put @values = [] in the roll method as suggested below. My only question now, is why the roll method thinks that @values is a NilClass instead of an array when I put @values = [] in an initialize method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby everything are objects. The Ruby interpreter assumes that all instance variables belong to the current object **self**. This is also true in a class definition. The role of **self** belongs to the class itself, so the instance variable @values belongs to the class. Don’t get confused! Instance variables of the class are different from instance
variables of that class’s objects. Also you don't need specify `return` keyword explicitly Try this:

```
class DiceSet
   attr_accessor :values       

   def roll(number_of_rolls)
     @values = []
     (1..number_of_rolls).each do |roll|
       @values << (1..6).to_a.sample
     end
     @values
   end
end

dice = DiceSet.new
dice.roll(5)
puts dice.values.class
assert dice.values.is_a?(Array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `DiceSet` instance has its own `@values`, and furthermore, the class `DiceSet` also has its own `@values`. They are all different from one another. If you want the instances and the class to share the same variable, you should use a class variable `@@values`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Cat
  attr_accessor :age
  def initialize
    @age = 12
  end
  @age = 6
  def meow
    puts "I'm #{@age}"
  end
  def self.meow
    puts "I'm #{@age}, going on #{@age+1}"
  end    
end
Cat.age = 4 # => NoMethodError: undefined method `age=' for Cat:Class
p Cat.age # =? NoMethodError: undefined method `age' for Cat:Class
Cat.meow # => I'm 6, going on 7
cat = Cat.new
p cat.age # => 12
cat.meow # => I'm 12
cat.age = 20 # => 20
cat.meow # => I'm 20
```

Were I to add

```
class << self
   attr_accessor :age
end
```

the first three lines of output would become:

```
Cat.age = 4 # => 4
p Cat.age # => 4
Cat.meow # => I'm 4, going on 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the declaration of @values = [] in the initialized method and your code should work as expected.

```
class DiceSet

  attr_reader :values
  def initialize()
     @values = []
  end

  def roll(number_of_rolls)
    (1..number_of_rolls).each do |roll|
      puts @values.class
      @values << (1..6).to_a.sample
    end
    return @values
  end
end
```